# MERGESORT never reaches the second array/list

Tags: python, mergesort

Here's the algorithm I'm trying to follow, from the CLSR book:

[image]

And here's my code in Python:

```
#merge sort

def merge_sort(A, p, q, r):
    n_prime = q - p + 1
    n_second = r - q
    L = [x for x in range(n_prime + 1)]
    R = [y for y in range(n_second + 1)]

    for i in range(n_prime):
        L[i] = A[p + i - 1]

    for j in range(n_second):
        R[j] = A[q + j]

    L[n_prime] = float("inf")
    R[n_second] = float("inf")

    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(p, r):
        if L[i] <= R[i]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        elif A[k] = R[j]:
            j += 1

    return A



A = [2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 1]

print(merge_sort(A, 0, 3, 7))
```

All the rest of the code works fine. According to VSCode Debugger, L and R are created without a hitch, but then in the last loop invariant, there's a problem: It never enumerates j. The `elif` condition is never met, so it never reaches the second list.

What's wrong with my implementation of the algorithm? I bet it has something to do with the fact that this book's arrays start with 1, but python list's indices start with 0. Why did they do this? Is there a general rule I should follow in translating the algorithms?

Thanks.

Comment: This algorithm is broken. Using sentinel values instead of testing index values agains array boundaries is an incorrect approach leading to bugs for pretty much all number types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably should be elif A[k] == R[j] (two "=" signs), what you wrote is an assignment.

I think I found the issue: it should be if L[i]<=R[**j**], not R[i].

Code that ran for me:

```
#merge sort
def merge_sort(A, p, q, r):
    n_prime = q - p + 1
    n_second = r - q
    L = [x for x in range(n_prime + 1)]
    R = [y for y in range(n_second + 1)]
    for i in range(n_prime):
        L[i] = A[p + i - 1]
    for j in range(n_second):
        R[j] = A[q + j]
    L[n_prime] = float("inf")
    R[n_second] = float("inf")
    i = 0
    j = 0
    print("L:", len(L), ", R:", len(R))
    for k in range(p, r):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            print("if", i)
            print(L[i])
            print(R[i])
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else: 
            print("else", k, j, A[k], R[j])
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
    return A
```

}

Comment: That's not the issue. It used to be the equation sign, then I changed it to assignment sign and made it into an `else` statement. Then I changed it back, and I forgot to make it into an equation sign. Overall, the issue does not stem from there. Thanks by the way.

Comment: If the input is an array of integers, this code will convert it into an array of floats. The idea of using sentinel values (infinity) instead of bounds checking indexes is probably a bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
elif A[k] = R[j]:
    j += 1
```

when the algorithm says:

```
else:
    A[k] = R[j]
    j += 1
```

A typo here will result in an "array index out of bounds" error:

```
if L[i] <= R[i]:
```

You likely meant:

```
if L[i] <= R[j]:
```

> What's wrong with my implementation of the algorithm?

It's incomplete; you only implemented the merge procedure, not the entire mergesort algorithm. Hence, running your code with the above corrections will output a partially sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the second time I've seen the CLSR version in the last week. I don't like the idea of using "sentinel values" (infinity) to avoid bounds checking on indexes, as it doesn't take that much more code, and won't work if A[] is an array of integers and already includes maximum values. The code has to be modified since the CLSR index range for arrays is 1 to n as opposed to 0 to n-1.

Here is example code that does a bounds check after each move, and if the end of a sub-run is reached, it appends the remainder of the remaining sub-run. Also the input parameters are beg (first index of run) and end (1 + last index of run), similar to C++ std::vector::begin() and std::vector::end(), which is the typical usage for merge sort.

```
def mergesort(a,beg,end):
    if (end-beg) > 1:
        mid=(beg+end)//2
        mergesort(a,beg,mid)
        mergesort(a,mid,end)
        merge(a,beg,mid,end)
def merge(a,beg,mid,end):
    left = a[beg:mid]
    right = a[mid:end]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = beg   
    while True:
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            a[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
            if(i < len(left)):
                continue
            a[k:end] = right[j:len(right)]
            break
        else:
            a[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
            if(j < len(right)):
                continue
            a[k:end] = left[i:len(left)]
            break
....
mergesort(a,0,len(a))   #call to merge sort to sort a[]
```

This is not an optimal implementation. It would be better to do a one time allocation of a working array, rather than allocating two working sub-arrays at each merge, and alternate the direction of merge with each level of recursion (or if doing bottom up merge sort, with each pass), to avoid copying data.